# Best place to store app-specific conf files in Laravel

Tags: laravel, configuration-files

I have some price lists that I can write, for easy maintenance, as arrays and use as a conf file, one per year.

I just wonder what would be the best place, semantically, to store these files :

- conf/prices/.php
- storage/app/prices/.php

Thanks for your advices

Comment: What is the data used for? Why do you think storing it in a file is easier than say a database? Currently your question is down to opinion and not a good fit for stackoverflow so will likely be closed. Add a bit more detail about your problem along with any reasons behind your choice.

Comment: @Peppermintology I disagree that this is opinion-based. Laravel has a clear convention for storing configuration files. As to why the OP prefers not to use a database, they explained their reasoning in the question.

Comment: @StephenLewis A `price list` is **not** configuration data. I didn't ask why the OP prefers to not use a database, I asked what makes them think a flat file is easier to maintain. Have a good day.  :)

Comment: It's a Quick&Dirty POC I have to code in hours.If it is validated, then evetything will managed in the database.
But for the moment, the only criteria was speed, so we mocked the data into flat config files..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuration files live in the `/config` directory. In your case, you can create a file at `config/prices.php`, and access it using [the global `config` helper](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/configuration#accessing-configuration-values).

Given the following `prices.php` config file:

```php
<?php

return [
    'cat' => 30,
    'dog' => 20,
    'owl' => 10
];
```

You can access the price of a cat using `config('prices.cat')`.